# date conversion in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have startdate and enddate as parameters in my report..

and in query I am checking condition

```
where (date BETWEEN (@BeginDate) AND (@EndDate))
```

the date field  in database is in `'2012-06-18 00:00:00.000'` format.

so do i need to do any conversions in the query..

I m getting no results in the report..

I also tried  where `(CONVERT(varchar, date , 101) BETWEEN (@BeginDate) AND (@EndDate))`
still no results.

Please advise.

Comment: What are the data type of the parameter defined in your query

Comment: If you run the query outside of the report, declaring the parameters and their values at the beginning, does it work there?

Answer (score 1):

If the date field only ever contains the date part (time part is always set to zero) then adding 1 day to the end date will return everything for '2012-06-18'.